# Google Sheets QUERY function dealing with dates

Tags: arrays, datetime, google-sheets, filter, google-query-language

I have a table (gDisplay) in my GoogleSheets file that looks like this:

[image]

So, in another table I can run this query without pain:

```
=QUERY(gDisplay!A2:I;"SELECT sum(F) WHERE A > '2021-09-01' ")
```

But I need to fetch last week results, and I was guessig that the query below could work:

```
=QUERY(gDisplay!A2:I;"SELECT sum(F) WHERE A > date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-8,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ")
```

But it's not working and I had no lucky searching for the answer. Any clue to fix this?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Hi there, here is it @player0. Look at table "Sumario7", O:15 cell:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b8TsL-ZoCXypyd01KNIIYvoP9oQh4o-TwHU6yqf6JyU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Ops, sorry, now I think it's open @player0:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b8TsL-ZoCXypyd01KNIIYvoP9oQh4o-TwHU6yqf6JyU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after 8 you need semicolon not comma:

```
=QUERY(gDisplay!A2:I;
 "SELECT sum(F) 
  WHERE A > date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-8; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

but try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(gDisplay!A2:I*1; "SELECT sum(Col6) WHERE Col1 > "&DATEVALUE(TODAY()-8)))
```

Comment: We're getting closer: now there is no error message but it returns nothing in the cell...

Comment: Cool, seems working :-)

Why "*1" after referencing the table/cells?

Comment: "Most likely you got mixed dataset. Query does not like that, so we force all values to be numeric instead of plain text and we use multiplication to do that"

That clever, indeed :-)

Thanks a lot, @player0 !!!!!

Comment: I'm seeing a strange behaivour (look at cel M:15, in "Sumario7): it's saying that Col12 didn't exist but it did. More than that, the query only works in Col9 and below.

Comment: @LuizC yes, thats true. your range is `A2:i` and column `i` is 9th column so if you want to do stuff with 12th your range needs to be `A2:L`